# Add Response Headers to ASP.NET Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add a processing time middleware to my ASP.NET Core WebApi like this

```
public class ProcessingTimeMiddleware  
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ProcessingTimeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        await _next(context);

        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Processing-Time-Milliseconds", new[] { watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() });
    }
}
```

But doing this throws an exception saying

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are readonly, reponse has already started.
```

How can I add headers to the response?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Never mind, the code is here

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        //To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
        context.Response.OnStarting(state => {
            var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Response-Time-Milliseconds", new[] { watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() });

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }, context);

        await _next(context);
    }
```

Comment: I would add also that await `_next(context)` should be the last statement (after `context.Response.Headers.Add`). More semantically correct.

Comment: Is there a .NET 4 equivalent or work around for this?  Still got some customers of Server 2003 :(

Comment: Is there a reason you used the state overload on OnStarting?

Comment: @MarkLopez because you need to convert the object (state) to HttpContext.  Other overload doesnt have this, but see what you mean, could just use context variable instead.

Comment: I mean, why not just let the closure capture the context variable to avoid the need to cast? Although, I later realized that the state is given in the API to not require developers to use a Lambda.

Comment: Would there be any reason why to use the callback if I know the value of the header at the time? Because I found a place where they use OnStarting callback, but then add a header with the value known at the time

Answer (score 17):

**Response headers can't be set after anything has been written to the response body**.Once you pass the request to next middleware and it writes to the Response, then the Middleware can't set the Response headers again.

However, there is a solution available using a Callback method.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse` defines the `OnStarting` Method, which *Adds a delegate to be invoked just before response headers will be sent to the client.* You can think this method as a callback method that will be called right before writing to the response starts.

```
public class ResponseTimeMiddleware
    {
        private const string RESPONSE_HEADER_RESPONSE_TIME = "X-Response-Time-ms";

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ResponseTimeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            context.Response.OnStarting(() => 
            {
                watch.Stop();
                var responseTimeForCompleteRequest = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                context.Response.Headers[RESPONSE_HEADER_RESPONSE_TIME] =  responseTimeForCompleteRequest.ToString(); 
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            return this._next(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively you can also add a middleware directly in the Startup.cs Configure method.

```
app.Use(next => async context =>
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-ResponseTime-Ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    await next(context);
});

app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: This will give me `OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started `

Comment: @cederlof You need to put this middleware before any other middleware.

Answer (score 5):

On a related note, without answering your question as such, there is now a `Server-Timing` specification, a standard header to provide durations, amongst other metrics. This should allow you to use

```
Server-Timing: processingTime;dur=12ms
```

You can find the specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/server-timing/

Answer (score 4):

Using an overload of OnStarting method:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();

    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        watch.Stop();

        context
              .Response
              .Headers
              .Add("X-Processing-Time-Milliseconds",
                        new[] { watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    watch.Start();

    await _next(context); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example headers already sent, when execution reaches context.Response.Headers.Add(...) statement.

You can try:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(x =>
    {
        watch.Stop();
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Processing-Time-Milliseconds", new[] { watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() });
    }, null);

    watch.Start();
    await _next(context);
    watch.Stop();
}
```

Comment: From which package is OnSendingHeaders  ?