# Adding Response Headers with Custom Middleware Asp.Net-Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 3 microservices and try to create correlation id to keep track of the every log issues. If corrID is not null when request comes, then I set it. If not, it is generated. And then passed to the next. I want to see  corrId for 3 services' logs. If I used the code below everything works well. But swagger does not work.

Exception: headers are read-only response has already started.

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                string key = context.Request.Headers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Equals("Correlation-ID"));

                var corrID = context.RequestServices.GetService<CorrelationID_Global>();

                if (corrID != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                    {

                        corrID.ID = context.Request.Headers[key].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        corrID.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                    }
                }

                await _next(context);

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(corrID?.ID))
                {               
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Correlation-ID", corrID.ID);
                }

            }
```

To solve swagger problem,  I change the last if statement using this link: [Add Response Headers to ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395227/add-response-headers-to-asp-net-core-middleware)

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(corrID?.ID))
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Correlation-ID", corrID.ID);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },null);
    }
```

However, this time I cannot see correlation-Id at responses' log of services.Thus corrID of requests' log changes as usual. How can I handle this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is to register `context.Response.OnStarting` callback before `await _next(context);` as one of the next middlewares in pipeline will start the response.

In other words, with the current implementation, your `OnStarting` callback is not fired as is registered too late. Change middleware code to

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(corrID?.ID))
{
    context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Correlation-ID", corrID.ID);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }, context);
}

await _next(context);
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for hours , I can't get a header to always be present in response regardless of 500 errors.  `context.Response.OnStarting()` is never fired in the case of an exception , With a hello world example . Should `context.Response.OnStarting` be called even in the case of exceptions ?