# Add property to all responses in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API with multiple endpoints. I'd like to add a property to all endpoint responses, without adding it to each endpoint response model individually.

Ex:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "Hello";
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; } = "World";
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyClass>> EndpointOne(POSTData data)
    {
        // implementation omitted
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyOtherClass>> EndpointTwo(POSTOtherData otherData)
    {
        // implementation omitted
    }
}
```

Calling either endpoint returns a JSON representation of `MyClass` or `MyOtherClass` as appropriate - i.e.

```
{ "MyProperty":"Hello" } or { "MyOtherProperty":"World" }
```

I want to add a property, say a string `ApiName`, to all endpoints in the API, so that the result of the above code would be either (as appropriate)

```
{ "MyProperty":"Hello", "ApiName":"My awesome API" }
```

or

```
{ "MyOtherProperty":"World", "ApiName":"My awesome API" }
```

Is there a way to hook into the JSON-stringified result just before returning and add a top-level property like that? If so, I presume I'd have to wire it up in `startup.cs`, so I've been looking at `app.UseEndpoints(...)` methods, but haven't found anything that's worked so far. Either it's not added the property, or it's replaced the original result with the new property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need a middleware.

Comment: Yes, you need a middleware. Heres a similar question with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395227/add-response-headers-to-asp-net-core-middleware

Comment: See [Configuring and extending the WCF runtime with behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/configuring-and-extending-the-runtime-with-behaviors#:~:text=There%20are%20four%20kinds%20of,and%20their%20associated%20EndpointDispatcher%20objects.)

Answer (score 7):

Use Newtonsoft.Json in your net web api

Register a custom contract resolver in Startup.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = CustomContractResolver.Instance);
```

The implementation:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    public static CustomContractResolver Instance { get; } = new CustomContractResolver();

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        // add new property
        ...
        properties.Add(newProp);
        return properties;
    }}
```

See more [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549680/json-net-add-property-to-every-class-containing-of-a-certain-type)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a base class with the shared property. Should work for both XML and JSON.

```
public class MyApiClass
{
    public string ApiName => "MyAwesomeApi";
}

public class MyClass : MyApiClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "Hello";
}

public class MyOtherClass : MyApiClass
{
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; } = "World";
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyClass>> EndpointOne(POSTData data)
    {
        // implementation omitted
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyOtherClass>> EndpointTwo(POSTOtherData otherData)
    {
        // implementation omitted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 0.02 cents says to implement an abstract base class.

Abstract class inheritance look similar to a standard inheritance.

```
    public class MyClass:MyAbstractClass
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Class Property")]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "Hello";
        }
    public class MyOtherClass:MyAbstractClass
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Class Property")]
        public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; } = "World";
        }
```

However the abstract class will allow you to implement additional features in the event you need them in the future.

```
    public abstract class MyAbstractClass{

        [JsonPropertyName("API Name")]
        public string ApiName{get;set;}="My Aweomse API";

        //Just a thought if you want to keep track of the end point names
        //while keeping your object names the same
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Always)]
        public string EndPointName{
            get{
                return get_endpoint_name();
                }}
        private string get_endpoint_name(){
            return this.GetType().Name;
            }

        //May as well make it easy to grab the JSON
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Always)]
        public string As_JSON{
            get {
                return to_json();
                }}

        private string to_json(){
            
            object _myObject = this;
            string _out;

            JsonSerializerOptions options = 
                new JsonSerializerOptions { 
                        WriteIndented = true };
            
            _out = 
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(_myObject, options);

            return _out;
        }
    }
```

Probably should have implemented a generic return object, then you could just loop through the task results.  I suppose you still can if you have the task return only the JSON string.

```
    public static void run(){

        Task<MyClass> _t0 = task0();
        Task<MyOtherClass> _t1 = task1();
        Task[] _tasks = new Task[]{_t0,_t1};

        Task.WhenAll(_tasks).Wait();
        
        Console.WriteLine(""
        +$"{_t1.Result.ApiName}:\n"
        +$"End Point: {_t1.Result.EndPointName}:\n"
        +$"JSON:\n{_t1.Result.As_JSON}");
        
        Console.WriteLine(""
        +$"{_t0.Result.ApiName}:\n"
        +$"End Point: {_t0.Result.EndPointName}:\n"
        +$"JSON:\n{_t0.Result.As_JSON}");
        
    }

    private static Task<MyClass> task0(){
        return Task.Run(()=>{
            Console.WriteLine("Task 0 Doing Something");
            return new MyClass();
        });
    }
    private static Task<MyOtherClass> task1(){
        return Task.Run(()=>{
            Console.WriteLine("Task 1 Doing Something");
            return new MyOtherClass();
        });
    }
```

And of course the aweosome...awesome:-) results:

[image: Results]

Another thought is that you could implement your two different tasks as abstract methods, but that's a different conversation all together.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the great answers, I prefer to use Action Filter and ExpandoObject.
In Program File you should add your custom action Filter.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    opt.Filters.Add<ResponseHandler>();
});
```

and ResponseHandler acts like below:

```
public class ResponseHandler : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in (context.Result as ObjectResult).Value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue((context.Result as ObjectResult).Value);
                expando.Add(propertyInfo.Name, currentValue);
            }
            dynamic result = expando as ExpandoObject;


            result.ApiName = context.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(result);
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```